# How do I use env.DATABASE_URL with Loopback in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, loopbackjs, heroku-postgres

I've removed datasources.json and added a datasources.local.js file.

`var postgresURI = process.env.DATABASE_URL; 
module.exports = { 
  db: { 
    defaultForType: 'postgresql', 
    connector: 'postgresql', 
    url: postgresURI 
  } 
};`

In model-config.json I have "dataSource": "db" set for all sections.

It throws the following error: User is referencing a dataSource that does not exist: "db".

I understand the error but not why it's being thrown. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documentation](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/datasources.json#datasources.json-Environment-specificconfiguration) says:

> You can override values set in datasources.json in the following files: datasources.local.js or datasources.local.json

So instead of removing datasources.json you might want to keep it with   a declaration of "db" in it. While in "datasources.local.js" you need to override environment specific setting which is the url.